# How to combine two records while keeping all referencing records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, sql-delete

PostgreSQL 11.1

I have struggled with this problem for a long time. (I have tried to improve the question from before).

Problem: A person has two different names in table tempA. Each name has its associated records in table tempB. How can I move all the records associated with one name to the other name, then delete the name?

Example:  I have two names --"Tom" and "Bob". I want to change all the records associated with "Bob" to "Tom", then remove "Bob" from the database.

How is this done while keeping the associated records in table tempb?

```
CREATE TABLE tempA
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE tempb
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    tempa_id integer NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT foo_bar_fk FOREIGN KEY (tempa_id)
        REFERENCES tempa (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)

INSERT INTO tempA (name) VALUES('tom');
INSERT INTO tempA (name) VALUES('bob');

INSERT INTO tempB (tempA_id, description) SELECT id, 'test1' FROM tempA WHERE tempA.name = 'tom';
INSERT INTO tempB (tempA_id, description) SELECT id, 'test2' FROM tempA WHERE tempA.name = 'tom';
INSERT INTO tempB (tempA_id, description) SELECT id, 'test3' FROM tempA WHERE tempA.name = 'bob';
INSERT INTO tempB (tempA_id, description) SELECT id, 'test4' FROM tempA WHERE tempA.name = 'bob';

Initial set:
-- tempA
id  name
1   "tom"
2   "bob"

id tempA_id  description
1   1      "test1"
2   1      "test2"
3   2      "test3"
4   2      "test4"
```

The goal I am trying to reach is:

```
--Desired Results
-- tempA
id  name
1   "tom"

-- tempB
id tempA_id  description
1   1       "test1"
2   1       "test2"
3   1       "test3"
4   1       "test4"
```

This is what I've tried, but it continues to fail:

```
BEGIN;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL  DEFERRED; 

-- from 'tom' to 'bob' -- when all is done 'tom' must be the name to keep.
WITH _in (name1, name2) AS(
        VALUES('tom','bob')
),
 _bob  AS(                 -- DELETING 'bob' record FROM tempA. 
        DELETE FROM tempA                     
        USING _in 
        WHERE (tempA.name = _in.name2)
        RETURNING tempA.*
)
UPDATE tempA        -- REPLACING 'bob' with 'tom'. REPLACING 'bobs' id with 'toms' id.
SET name = _in.name1, id = _tom.id
FROM _in 
JOIN _bob ON (_bob.name = _in.name2)
JOIN tempA _tom ON (_tom.name = _in.name1)
WHERE (tempA.id = _bob.id);

COMMIT;
```

*ERROR:  update or delete on table "tempa" violates foreign key constraint "foo_bar_fk" on table "tempb"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "tempb"*.

It seems I cannot get the UPDATE to occur before the Delete is enforced.

Any help is most appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to `update` the child table first, then `delete` from the parent - the foreign key constraints prevents you from proceeding the other way around.

Consider:

```
with 
    names (to_keep, to_del) as(values('tom','bob')),
    upd as (
        update tempB
        set tempA_id = a_keep.id
        from names n
        inner join tempA a_keep on a_keep.name = n.to_keep
        inner join tempA a_del  on a_del.name  = n.to_del
        where tempB.tempA_id = a_del.id
        returning a_del.id
    )
delete from tempA 
using upd
where tempA.id = upd.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ca0d49d879491f64fc6a84728a6419d)**

Comment: As time goes on, I expect there to be many more tables like tempB--tables which are unknown at the time the procedure code (the sql) is written.  I was hoping to use the foreign key "cascade" mechanism to "naturally" cause those tables to be correctly updated. That is, I'd like to not have to rewrite the sql every time I add a new table like tempB. ( I hope I said that right). Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind in using a trigger to "move" the referencing table records from one surrogate key to another--before the delete or update ???

Comment: "Demo on DB Fiddle" gives: 22023ERROR: invalid hexadecimal digit: "="

Comment: @AlanWayne: sorry, there was an unwanted trailing `=` in the fiddle link.

Comment: @AlanWayne: the cascading mechanisms of the foreign keys cannot do what you want here (that is, reaffect children records to an existing parent)...

Comment: O.K. But I feel sure this is a common problem--so outside of this approach, any suggestions on how most people would resolve the same issue--that of combining two records into one without losing information in the subtables? Would another table be needed to record the id's from tempA?  Then all subtables would reference that table, and not tempA at all?

Comment: @AlanWayne: not so common in my experience. In normal situation, you should not find yourself reaffecting children records to other parents... I am unsure that there is a common path to solve this.